# Allergies: should we test them proactively?

Tags: health, allergies

If a child has had no allergic reaction (yet), should we test her for allergies anyway, just in case? Or, is it enough to react after an allergic reaction?

Answer (score 9):

If there has been no allergic reaction then there is no need to test with two exceptions.

- Family history of a lethal reaction. For example if Grandma is allergic to fish, and Mom is allergic to fish, then be extra careful with fish around the child.
- Doctors advise allergen testing. I'm not one to say blindly follow doctors' advice, but if a doctor is telling you to get the testing done, then get it done.

With most allergies, common signs will show LONG before a lethal reaction occurs. For example, hives, rashes, watery eyes and running nose will all be very evident with non-food allergies long before any serious complications arise (normally). Food allergies often present as a sore throat or upset stomach, long before the "I can't breath" point (normally).

Even if you do get allergen testing, they don't test for everything, just common things, or things they think have triggered the reaction. The testing can be very unpleasant if the list is long.

Best advise is ask your primary care physician.

Comment: Also, we were told for our daughter that with babies (under a year old), allergy tests are very unreliable. I don't know if it applies to all tests though, as she had skin problems only.

Comment: "With most allergies, common signs will show LONG before a lethal reaction occurs." - is there research backing this up? It sounds intuitively correct, but so do many other things that aren't actually medically sound.

Comment: Honestly, not really. You can research "Anaphylaxis" that's the "food one" but most of what I can find on google is fear mongering and product sales. If you believe the first few links your better off just starving your self to death then risking eating anything. But, as a person with non-food allergies, and husband of someone with food allergies. I can tell you, in my experience, that even the food my wife is allergic too won't cause a fatal reaction, before it starts causing her other unpleasant side effects. But when in doubt ask a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no allergic symptoms you don't actually need to test it proactively. Yes if your child has running nose or constant cough or some ongoing allergic symptoms. it is time to find out what is the reason & how it can be handled. Know complete details about childhood allergies & treatment plan here. http://www.ssdhospital.com/childhood-allergies/